# A txt file with scores(92 92 92 92 92) get assigned all A's, but with scores(92 10 70 95 84) 92 and 95 get assigned 'B'?

Tags: java, arrays, debugging, methods

So I need help debugging my code. The problem with my code is that incorrect grades are assign to each score in my array. My file reads in a txt file which include first name[space]last name[tab]score. It then stores them in arrays, calculates the mean and standard deviation of the scores and then should assign letter grades to the scores, but the thing is that if I rewrite the txt file to (92 92 92 92 92) they all are assigned 'A' which is right, but when the txt file is(92 10 70 95 84) the 92 and 95 get assigned 'B' instead of 'A', which is the only problem. I have spent hours trying to find out why it does this, but have had no luck. He is how to calculate the letter grades:

A = mean + standard <= score, B = mean + (standard/3) <= score < mean + standard, C = mean - (standard/3) <= score < mean + (standard/3), D = mean - standard <= score < mean - (standard/3), F = score < mean - standard

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;    
import java.util.Scanner;

public class ScannerReadFileSplit {

public static int[] scores = new int[5];
public static String[] names = new String[5];
public static char[] grades = new char[5];
public static int mean = 0;
public static double standard = 0.0;

public static void main(String[] args) {


    readData();       
    mean = fndMean();
    standard = fndStandard();

    for(int x = 0; x < scores.length; x++) {
      if(mean + standard <= scores[x]) {
        grades[x] = 'A';

      } if( (mean + (standard/3) <= scores[x]) && (scores[x] < mean + standard)) {
        grades[x] = 'B';

      } if( (mean - (standard/3) <= scores[x]) && (scores[x] < mean+(standard/3))) {
        grades[x] = 'C';

      } if( (mean - standard <= scores[x]) && (scores[x] < mean - (standard/3))) {
        grades[x] = 'D';

      }
      if(scores[x] < mean - standard) {
        grades[x] = 'F';
      }
    }

    System.out.printf("%-22s%-22s%-22s\n", "Names", "Scores", "Grade");
        for(int k=0; k<5; k++) {
            System.out.printf("%-22s%-22d%-22c\n", names[k], scores[k], grades[k]);
           }
           System.out.println();
}


  //Method called readData() that reads input from the file and stores the names
  //in an array called names and scores in an array called scores. * Each names has
  //to be a seperate line and scores have to be seperated by a tab.
  public static void readData() {

    File file = new File("NamesScore.txt");
    int i = 0;

    try {

     Scanner scanner = new Scanner(file);
        while (scanner.hasNextLine()) {

            String line = scanner.nextLine();
            String [] words = line.split("\t");

            names[i] = words[0];
            scores[i] = Integer.parseInt(words[1]);
            i++;
          }

        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
          e.printStackTrace();
          System.exit(0);
      }
  }

  //Method called fndMean() that goes through the scores array, adds all elements
  //and then divides that sum by the number of elements, which then stores that value
  //in a variable mean1 then returns that value.
  public static int fndMean() {
        int mean1 = 0;
        int sum = 0;
        for(int j = 0; j < scores.length; j++) {
            sum += scores[j];
        }
        mean1 = (sum/(scores.length));
        System.out.printf("The mean of the scores is: %d\n", mean1);
        return mean1;
    }

  //Method called fndStandard() that finds the standard deviation of the scores by using
  //the following formula. That value is then stores in a variable standardDeviation1 then
  //returns that value 
  public static double fndStandard() {
         double sd = 0;
         for(int i = 0; i < scores.length; i++) {
             sd += ((scores[i] - mean) * (scores[i] - mean)) / (scores.length - 1);
         }
         double standardDeviation1 = Math.sqrt(sd);
         System.out.printf("The standard deviation is: %.2f\n", standardDeviation1);
         return standardDeviation1;
    }  
}
```

Comment: One comment I suggest is, instead of having `if`s for other letters, if you use `else if`s, you can get rid of secondary conditions and overwriting values.

Comment: Isn't condition `B = mean + (standard/3) <= score < mean + standard` is `true` for 92 and 95 in _(92 10 70 95 84)_ ? have you calculated it manually and compare the result?

Answer (score 0):

For the second case, you have a mean of 52.2 and a std of ~40. For 92, `(mean + (standard/3) <= scores[x]) && (scores[x] < mean + standard))`computes to 52.2+40/3<92 and 92<52.2+40 to be assigned a B, so it looks correct.